# send picture with telebot in python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import telebot
import urllib.request
import pyautogui
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN", parse_mode=None)

@bot.message_handler('start')
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hi Wellcome To Server Manager Bot")
    enter code here
@bot.message_handler('getip')
def send_targetip(message):
    target_ip = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ip.42.pl/short")
    ip = target_ip.read()
    bot.reply_to(message,ip)
@bot.message_handler('screen')
def capture_screen(send_photo):
    screenimage = pyautogui.screenshot("screen.png")
    screenimage.save("C:\\Users\\HO3IN\\Desktop\\screen.png")
    photo = open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\screen.png",'rb')
    bot.send_photo(capture_screen,photo)
    photo.close()
bot.polling()
```

I can't send screenshot from bot, show me this error:

> **init**.py:515 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad
> Request: chat not found"

Answer (score 1):

You should use "message.chat.id" instead of "message".

```
bot.reply_to(message.chat.id,"Hi")
bot.reply_to(message.chat.id,ip)
bot.send_photo(send_photo.chat.id,photo)
```